# how to use [arr[0] integerValue] in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi there How to convert this line of code in Swift:

arr is a array of element like this [00:18.84].

```
double startTime = [arr[0] integerValue] * 60 + [arr[1] floatValue];
```

Comment: try this var startTime = Double(Float(arr[0] * 60) + arr[1])

Comment: no it will not....its depend upon what `arr` contains..

Answer (score 0):

```
let startTime = arr[0].integerValue* 60 + arr[1].floatValue
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In swift to convert a value to `Int` you do this:

```
let a = Int(11.22) // Will give 11
```

And for `Float` :

```
let b = Float(11) //will give 11.0
```

Also in Swift you can not do operation between Int and Float, they have to be of same type.

```
let startTime = Float(Int(arr[0]) * 60) + Float(arr[1])
```

And if you want result as `Double` then you need to cast your answer to `Double` :

```
    let startTime = Double(Float(Int(arr[0]) * 60) + Float(arr[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are converting a string with the format `HH:mm` or `mm:ss` to a minute/second count, am I right?. It should be something like that:

```
let string = "12:12"
let arr = string.components(separatedBy: ":")

let startTime = Double(Int(arr[0])!) * 60 + Double(arr[1])!
```

You have to make sure that `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are in the correct format otherwise the app will crash

Comment: Hi lorenzoliveto
Thanks for your reply.
arr is a array of element like this [00:18.84].

Comment: @Zetao `00:18.84` seems a string. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `arr` is an array of string like `let arr = ["1", "2"]` then you should use following.

```
if arr.count > 1 {

   let startTime: Double = (Double(arr[0]) ?? 0) * 60 + (Double(arr[1]) ?? 0)
    print(startTime)
}
```